# Keep the parent li highlighted when a submenu was accesed

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

Hello guys how can I have all  the time the parent "`li`" highlighted with a background or to give a class with some properties from css on a drop down navigation menu when a sub menu was accessed? something like will indicate in which section of menu it is navigating and that background remain all the time highlighted till will change the menu.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">About </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Programmes</a>
        <ul class="secondLevel">
            <li><a onClick="ajaxCall();" href="">Undergraduate</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Postgraduate</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Academics</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Facilities</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
} #menu {
    width: 958px;
    /*margin: 60px auto;*/
    border: 1px solid #222;
    background-color: #111;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#444, #111);

box-shadow:
    0 1px 1px #777;
} #menu:before, #menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
} #menu:after {
    clear: both;
} #menu {
    zoom: 1;
} #menu li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 #444;
    position: relative;
} #menu a {
    float: left;
    padding: 11px 40px;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
} #menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fafafa;
} * html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
} #menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 38px;
    left: 0;
    right: -1px;
    z-index: 1000000;
    background: #444;
    background: linear-gradient(#444, #111);

box-shadow:
    0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);

transition:all
    .2s

ease-in-out;
} #menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
} #menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 150px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: -1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
} #menu ul li {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111, 0 2px 0 #666;
} #menu ul li:last-child {
    box-shadow: none;
} #menu ul a {
    padding: 10px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
} #menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
} #menu ul li:first-child > a {
    /*border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;*/
    padding: 11px 13px;
} #menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
} #menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0;
} #menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
} #menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #000;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
} #menu ul li:last-child > a {
    /*border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px*/;
    padding: 11px 20px;
}
```

## jsFiddle

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you mean?  I am still a little confused.

Comment: What happens when you click on a submenu? Does it load another page?

Comment: @chockleyc http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#imagemap cand you see menu in left how remain with a different background when a section was selected, I want something similar but in my case I want that even when a sub menu was accesed.

Comment: @ Steve nope is loading via ajax other section in the same page and the menu is static .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery adding a click event on the `.secondLevel` elements:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.secondLevel').find('li').click(function(){

       //removing the previous selected menu state
       $('#menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');

       //adding the state for this parent menu
       $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');
    });
});
```

And creating the `active` state for the menu:

```
#menu li.active{
    background: #ccddff;
}
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/L94N6/2/

## Update

In order to make it work with both lists, you could add a simple condition depending on the list class:

```
$('#menu').find('li').click(function(){
   //removing the previous selected menu state
   $('#menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');

    //is this element from the second level menu?
    if($(this).closest('ul').hasClass('secondLevel')){
         $(this).parents('li').addClass('active');

    //this is a parent element
    }else{
         $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/L94N6/4/

Comment: yes something like this but I want to do that when sub menu was selected or other simple menu from drop-down nav menu. For example for about does not put the active class.

Comment: Wouldn't $('#menu').find('.active').removeClass('active') be more efficient in that removeClass will only get called once and not for every li?

Comment: @GGJ You could also do `$('#menu').find('li.active').removeClass('active');` if you wish.

Comment: @Steve Another question, in my real menu I have 3 levels, firts extind another menu and the second menu extind dropdown I must acomodate script with las level of my menu, right ?

Comment: @burebistaruler better if you open a new question with more details.

Comment: What if it if a 3 level menu? Thanks. I tried that and it didnt work for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300274/how-to-keep-all-parents-menu-item-same-style

Comment: @SiKni8 you should open a new question for it, you'll get more answers.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your request correctly you merely have to add

```
#menu li:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

This is because the hover state of the li of the drop down parent persists when the content is under hover.

Comment: I think the OP means to show this background color for the active parent tab, where active includes if the active page is one of the submenu items.

Comment: @GGJ not on hover I want to have the "li" top menu permanently selected after a submenu was picked.

Comment: Then Steve has your answer using jQuery to traverse up the tree and set a class. One issue you might get with the solution is on clicking the a and it calling a function if you stop propagation then the click event on the li will never fire, also if your a element is smaller then the li the event could fire setting the class without the link triggering.